# How to retrieve the information of a sproc using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Now that I need to retrieve the information (mainly the name and the parameters info) of all the sproc(s) in SQL Server 2008 R2 the DB, does JDBC support it? If this is not possible, if given a sproc name, can I retrieve the information of the specific sproc - the parameters' info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve information about all stored procedures using [`DatabaseMetaData.getProcedures(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedures%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

The parameters `procedureNamePattern` (and `columnNamePattern`) expect an SQL `LIKE` pattern, so if you want all procedures, you can call it as:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = ...;
dbmd.getProcedures(null, null, "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve stored procedure results from JDBC using SQL Server.

There are multiple ways.

1. When using JDBC directly, register output parameters in a CallableStatement. http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/
2. When using Spring, you can declare output parameters using SimpleJDBCCall. http://tothepointtalks.blogspot.com/2009/12/execute-stored-procedure-in-spring-with.html